# PHP + Preg_replace : Remove the part after '+' in email

Tags: php, email, preg-replace

In order to promote a website, I allow subscribers to invite friends by email and I reward them.

But, some of them, used an email list like:

```
user@example.com, user+1@example.com, user+2@example.com
```

And all that emails refers to `user@example.com` so they are all valid.

What is the preg_replace pattern that remove the part after '+' sign so I can, after that, explode and use array_unique to remove duplicate emails ?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site wasn't meant to have others do your entire job, you know.

Comment: There is no rule saying emails of the form X+Y@... have to go to X, that is just something gmail does.

Comment: I'm sorry Bart you thought I give you my job to do: If I didn't give any code, it's because none of them works. Here bellow is the code I found it works.

Comment: @Hassinus: that's okay, but please do indicate in any new questions you may ask what you have tried so far and where you get stuck. This helps us to appreciate the questions more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it. Juste remove the part between '+' and '@' using:

```
preg_replace('/\+(.)*@/', '@', $emails);
```

Hope it will help.

P.S.: I'm sorry Bart you thought I give you my job to do: If I didn't give any code, it's because none of them works.

Comment: @Dan ?? Your solution works too, but mine is a little bit different: It juste removes the string between + and @. Yours rewrite the entire email. Both are OK. I just added mine as another potential solution. No kidding at all.

Answer (score 3):

easy

```
$email = preg_replace('/\+[^@]*/i' , '' , $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
preg_replace('/(.+)\+.+(@.+)/', '$1$2', $mail);
```

if `user+@example.com` should also be replaced, you can take

```
preg_replace('/(.+)\+.*(@.+)/', '$1$2', $mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

to use preg_replace in your case, you can do the following:

```
$email = 'user+1@example.com';
$email = preg_replace("#(.+)\+.*@(.*)#", '$1@$2', $email);
```